Keep most common line from each set of duplicates of a column
I have a relatively complicated Bash problem. I have a two-column CSV file that contains duplicate values in the first column, as well as duplicates within those duplicate values (in the second column). For each of the duplicates in the first column, I need to keep only the lines which have the most frequent values in the second column.
For example, if there are the following 5 lines with 1234 in the first column:
1234,000
1234,000
1234,000
1234,111
1234,111

...only one line containing 1234,000 should be kept and the other 4 lines deleted. Of course this then needs to be repeated across the entire file for all duplicates other than 1234.
EDIT: Further clarification - if 1234,000 and 1234,111 both occur the same number of times then one of each should be kept, deleting the extras.
I could use one of these solutions to find the most frequently occurring line, but the hard part here is figuring out how to do that for each set of duplicates.

re: I prefer not to risk the integrity of my data on something I hacked together myself from tools I barely know. - how are you going to risk the integrity of your data? just have your script write the output to a new/different file

presort the data file, for a given value in the 1st column use one of the solutions from the link you reference in the question, when the value in the 1st column changes then print the 'most common' row(s) for the previous value, reset your counters and accumulation variables and start looking for 'most common' for the new value

@markp-fuso When you're working with single files that contain millions of records, no amount of backing up is going to stop a hacky solution from running and potentially deleting records that shouldn't have been deleted, and the only way you find out that happened is when a solution is well into production, at which point it's already cost someone money. Again, thanks for the downvote, although I'm unsure why you're downvoting a solution you just outlined an answer to - either you think it's answerable or you don't... or you're downvoting for a reason that has nothing to do with the question.

if you're unable to easily and accurately make a backup of your data then you should address that issue first; if you're unable to verity the accuracy of your coding solution then redesign the solution to never overwrite the original data but instead create a new data set  ... this would be akin to maintaining versions of your data (like you maintain versions of your code, right?); these are basic, standard, common sense approaches when dealing with any volume of 'critical' data (I deal with this on a daily basis as a DBA managing billions of records of data)

@markp-fuso So you're telling me that you know every single record of your data and would notice if one of them was deleted (without relying on the DBMS to tell you)? No, common sense is to process your text DBs using code written by someone more experienced and not something you hacked together yourself because someone on a forum told you you needed an MRE. VCS does not exist for text DBs and backups are a last resort - once again, there is no way for you to know text DB data is missing until something goes wrong because a record is missing in production, at which point it's already too late.

sysadmins make backups of filesystems all the time; backup the filesystem where you data file is stored; again, a very basic operation when dealing with any sort of 'critical' data; if you're unable to validate the accuracy of your code and/or don't know how to make backups of your critical data then it sounds like someone should speak to management about addressing these issues

@markp-fuso Evidently you have a reading comprehension problem, since you seem incapable of realising I've already addressed your backups point twice and yet still keep banging on about them. Once more: by the point you have to use backups, the damage is already done. Data integrity is about using common sense to prevent having to resort to backups. Time to admit you're out of your depth when it comes to data that isn't inside of a DBMS and move on.

With awk:
BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = ","
}

{
  col1s[$1]
  if (++ndup[$0] == 1)
    uniq[$1, ++nuniq[$1]] = $0
}

END {
  for (col1 in col1s) {
    max = 0
    recs = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= nuniq[col1]; i++) {
      cand = uniq[col1, i]
      if (ndup[cand] > max) {
        max = ndup[cand]
        recs = cand ORS
      }
      else if (ndup[cand] == max) {
        recs = recs cand ORS
      }
    }

    printf "%s", recs
  }
}


Wow, that may be the most complicated awk code I've ever seen. Is it me or is it missing a file input? awk -V prints GNU Awk 5.2.2, how does that deal with ties?

@HashimAziz My bad, it always chooses the earlier record. It's run like awk '...' file, you specify the input on the command line.

@HashimAziz You can also put it in a script file, and use awk -f dups.awk filename

@oguzismail To clarify, if 1234,000 and 1234,111 both occur the same number of times, will this solution keep both or select the earliest? Is there any risk of this solution losing data?

@HashimAziz Nope, it selects both. I updated after seeing your edit

Finally managed to get around to running this and testing it as best as I could by calculating line counts with and without dupes. Assuming my maths is right there's a small discrepancy of about 50 extra records, so well within margin of error for the dataset and definitely no loss of data - probably just down to a few badly formatted records in the original. Thanks for a great solution. Now it's time to write some unit tests.

I'm not sure I understood your goal.
If your input is this
1234,000
1234,000
1234,000
1234,111
1234,111
5236,000
5236,000
5236,222
5236,222
5236,222

You can use the great Miller and run
mlr --csv -N count-similar -g 1,2 then \
top -f count -g 1 -a -n 1 then \
cut -f 1,2 input.csv

to have
1234,000
5236,222


mlr --csv -N count-similar -g 1,2: This counts the occurrences of each unique pair in the first two columns.

--csv -N: Specifies that the input is CSV without headers.
count-similar -g 1,2: Groups by columns 1 and 2 and counts the similar pairs.


then top -f count -g 1 -a -n 1: This command finds the most frequent pair for each group defined by the first column.

top -f count: Sorts by the count field (count is the field name generated by count-similar).
-g 1: Groups the results by the first column.
-a -n 1: Selects the top 1 entry per group.


then cut -f 1,2: This extracts only the first and second columns from the results.


You did understand the goal/dataset correctly, and I upvoted for the extra solution that may be useful to someone coming across this through Google, but using external tools wasn't possible for me. Looks like a powerful tool though, much more concise than the awk equivalent.

Thank you @HashimAziz I didn't realize you couldn't install anything, otherwise I wouldn't have answered you. Yes it is a great tool.
